# What do I have to change in my syntax for it to work in MS SQL Server from Informix

Tags: sql, sql-server, informix

I'm currently updating a lot of our queries to work again in our new ERP-Release, where we will be working with MS SQL Server, swapping away from our current Informix database. Many are just simple Date-Format changes but this one I am unable to translate.

It really only is the following line:

```sql
round((GETDATE() - max(l105.dataen))::interval second(9) to second::char(10)::int
/ 60 / 60, 3)
```

I simply can't grasp what the part starting at the colons (`::`) is doing or what function it is.

I hope someone maybe can identify it.

Comment: If that is one of "our queries" then surely someone in your organization knows exactly what it does and how it is used. In general you cannot use dates in mathematical expressions. This looks like some sort of "difference" in hours (?) between current datetime and the value in a column - but i have no experience in informix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Informix, subtracting two DATETIME values results in an INTERVAL.  The `<value>::<type>` notation is a shorthand for `CAST(<value> AS <type>)`.  Therefore, there are three consecutive casts:

1. `::interval second(9) to second`
2. `::char(10)`
3. `::int`

By default, if you subtract two DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND values, you will get an INTERVAL DAY(n) TO SECOND value.  The first cast converts that to `INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND` — a number of seconds; the second cast converts the result to `CHAR(10)` because there isn't a direct conversion from `INTERVAL` to numeric types; the third cast converts the string to an `INT`.  That gives the integer number of seconds; it is divided by `60` twice (effectively, divided by 3600) to convert the seconds into hours.

The result is then rounded to 3 decimal places.

- **So, the overall operation calculates the number of hours between two times.**

The two times are the current time and the most recent value in the `l105.dataen` column (the `MAX` expression).  Presumably, there is a GROUP BY clause somewhere in the SELECT statement that this is a part of.

You will likely need to use a 'time difference' function in MS SQL Server, and maybe the function allows you to control the presentation of the result as a number of hours and fractions of an hour.

Judging from [DATEDIFF function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), you will need to use something like:

```
DATEDIFF(hh, MAX(l105.dataen), GETDATE())
```

However, that returns an integer value for the difference in hours.  You may prefer to get the time in seconds and divide by 3600 to get a fractional value:

```
DATEDIFF(ss, MAX(l105.dataen), GETDATE()) / 3600.0
```

<sup>*No database server was consulted to ensure the veracity of the suggested translation.*</sup>

Comment: wow, thank you very much that answer was perfect your solution also works just the way i wanted. Awesome thank you very much, never knew that <value>::<type> was just a shorthand notation for the CAST-Function.

Comment: @kuy: I don't know of any other DBMS than Informix that uses the `::` notation for casting.  There may be some, but it is not part of the SQL standard (the `CAST` operator is standard).